# Transformer winding

Tags: transformer

[image]My EI core size is 32mm*60mm giving 368 W maximum power.I want to make 30 0 30 5A secondary out from transformer. according to my calculation dual winding of 75 turns for 30 0 30 V if i want another 25 0 25 V 5A from same winding with same center tap.Can it possible after dual 62 turn to take wire out for 25 0 25 V and continue up 75 turn which will give 30 0 30 final out from secondary.(Note that I will not use both voltage at same time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work as you suggest but you need to take account of loading effects on the transformer and leakage inductance plays a part in this. The upshot being that you might choose to add a turn or two to all secondary windings or maybe remove a few turns from the primary. This means that open circuit the secondaries might be a little high but, under loading conditions, the output will be nominally correct. It's optional.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. is their any limit to take multiple voltages from same secondary winding .

Comment: @Sandeep not that I'm aware of but clearly the more connections there are the more eddy current losses there could be but it will be minor.

Comment: Hello Andy aka this core window aria is 768 mm can its enough for winding.

Comment: @Sandeep it's impossible to say anything else other than what I've said without having a core and trying to wind one.